# type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I found that the problem is in std::map but I have no clue why.

ObjectFactory.hpp

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

template <
        class TAbstractProduct,
        typename IdentifierType,
        class TProductCreator = std::function<TAbstractProduct*()>
          >
class ObjectFactory
{
public:
    using product_type = TAbstractProduct;
    using id_type = IdentifierType;
    using creator_type = TProductCreator;

    ObjectFactory() = default;

    bool registerType(const id_type& id, creator_type callback) {
        typename TCallbackMap::value_type el{id, callback};
        auto res = callbacks.insert(el);
        return true;
    }

    bool unregisterType(const id_type& id) {
        return (callbacks.erase(id) == 1);
    }

    product_type* create(id_type id) const {
        auto iterator = callbacks.find(id);
        if (iterator != callbacks.end()) {
            return iterator->second();
        }
    }

private:
    using TCallbackMap = std::map<IdentifierType, TProductCreator>;
    TCallbackMap callbacks;
};
```

ShapeHierarchy.hpp

```
#include <string>

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual std::string text() const {
        return "Shape";
    }
    static int id() {
        return 0;
    }
};
//other shape derived classes...
```

ObjectFactoryExecution

```
#include "ObjectFactory.hpp"
#include "CloneFactory.hpp"
#include "ShapeHierarchy.hpp"

using ShapeFactory = ObjectFactory<Shape, std::string, std::function<Shape*()>>;

class ObjectFactoryExecution
{
public:
    void execute() {
        ShapeFactory* factory = new ShapeFactory();
        /*factory->registerType(Rhombus::id(), []() { return new Rhombus(); });
        factory->registerType(Triangle::id(), []() { return new Triangle(); });
        factory->registerType(Circle::id(), []() { return new Circle(); });*/

    }
};
```

Shape
It seems to me that some types are not fully determined in the scope of ShapeFactory, so map cannot properly process it, but I don't understand which.

Issue text is: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template struct first'
if (__p.first < __n)
^~~

Comment: Works fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/wf4s9C). Did you miss some includes?

Comment: ObjectFactory and Shape are in separate headers and both are included into "main" header (there's another class that uses them). Maybe my std::map is broken. I'll edit question with real code.

Comment: Warning for later: `create` does not return on all paths.

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко That doesn't help much. Create a [mcve]. You can use several files on some online compiler to show the issue.

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко At the very least you need to show your includes in your code example.

Comment: Changed the example with includes.

Comment: What is `ShapeFactory`?

Comment: Precision matters. Obviously the problem you're hunting here means the program won't run, but a [mre] for a compiler error should almost compile. The only error should be the one reported in the question (though that error sometimes causes a storm of other messages.)  What you've given, even after replacing `ShapeFactory` with `ObjectFactory`, produces other errors. This is still not **reproducible**.

Comment: `ShapeFactory` expects a `string` for ID, but your (commented out) `registerType` calls appear to pass `int`.

Comment: I still can't  explain why you people can't reproduce the error. It gives me this also:
In function '_OutputIterator std::__sample(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag, _OutputIterator, _Cat, _Size, _UniformRandomBitGenerator&&)':
Idk why sample is called for std::map on creation/

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, some files on my mingw compiler were corrupted, error is not reproducible.